# GitHub - restrict number of commits for pull request

Tags: github

I wanted to know if there is any way I can restrict the number of commits in a particular pull request?

I means if number of commits difference is higher than either it won't allow you to create a pull request or it will be automatically rejected.

Comment: Try https://danger.systems . It is capable of detecting merge commits, and rejecting the PR, so it might be able to count the number of commits. You may have to write your own plugin.